# UICollectionView scrolls out of view when scrollToItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am having trouble with the `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` method in my collectionView. When scrolling to the last item, it seems as the collectionView scrolls out of view. When I try to scroll up after that, then collectionView is at the bottom.

```
NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:collectionView] - 1;

NSInteger item = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;

NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

[Example Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S1aJeLgFI4&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I think it is because of item try to -1 from item

Comment: Ive tried it with and without the -1, it either crashes cause of my data array or scrolls out of bounds.

Comment: Check item count if count is 0 then it will be -1

Comment: i think i might have to do with the fact that my cells are dynamic